# .net mvc 4 model binding with special characters

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to create a model-class for a json object like:

```
 { "model" : { "@foo": "bar", "#baz": "fu" }}
```

How to write a model or rather declare the class variables if I want to pass the json `model`, with the special characters `@` and `#` in their variable names, to my Controller:

```
$http.post('@Url.Action("myController","test")', model, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' } })

 public class MyModel 
    {
//       public string @foo { get; set; }
 //      public #bar { get; set; }
    }

 public ActionResult myController(MyModel model) {

            return View();
        }
```

There are two simple solutions.

1. iterate the json object and change variable names.
2. post the json as string `JSON.stringify(data)` and serialize it at my own

like it is described below:

```
public ActionResult myController(string model)
{
    var ser = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavascriptSerializer();
    Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = ser.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(model);

    // Do something with the dictionary
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Json.NET then you can use `[JsonProperty]` attribute to decorate the property name:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "@foor")]
public string Foo { get; set; }

[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "#bar")]
 public Bar { get; set; }
```

Comment: Hi. I accepted your answer, was just waiting for other suggestion. But yours is perfect, thx.